# CasperJS not scraping paginated data except first

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to scrape [this](https://career4.successfactors.com/career?company=Plantronics&career_ns=job_listing_summary)

The first page is loading correct but whenever I run the below code, it doesnt give any error and returns data of the first page. I tried several ways but was unable to scrape the other pages data.

```
    this.thenClick('tr[class^="bottomPaginator"] li:nth-child(5)').then(function() {
        this.waitFor(function() {
            return /\d+ Jobs/.test(this.fetchText('span.jobCount'));
        }, processPage, terminate, 4000);
    });
```

Please let me know if this is possible with CasperJS.

I am interested in PY Scrapy as-well if possible.

Thanks

Comment: “Please let me know if this is possible with CasperJS”. Scraping is possible with any web client, so to that I can answer “yes” :)

Comment: you answered the 2nd part but im unable to scrape content of the paginated data. how to do with casperjs. can you plz help.